# Multi Key Multi Value map possible?

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I see there is a `Multimap` that allows duplicate values for a key http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

I also noticed guava has a `Table` which allows multiple keys, but not duplicated values. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html

I can't find anywhere where there is a "Table" that allows duplicated values, or a "Multimap" that allows multiple keys.

Is this something that exists already, or would I have to implement this myself?

I just want to implement a `Multimap` with 2 keys i.e. `<K1, K2, Value>`

Comment: Do you mean that `k1`, `k2` should be used as a compound key for one entry? Or that a value can be indexed by either `k1` or `k2`?

Comment: K1 and K2 should both be compound key for that one value

Comment: Okay, [Louis nailed it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34078721/3474) then. (He develops Guava.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing I'm aware of that supports that need.  However, it's not terribly difficult to just e.g. use a `Multimap<MyK1AndK2Pair, Value>` where you write a custom pair class yourself, or conversely to use a `Table<K1, K2, List<Value>>` and manage things yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What about nested maps?

```
Multimap<K1, Multimap<K2, Value>> doubleMultiMap = new HashMultiMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use MultiKeyMap of Apache Commons. Its description says -

A Map implementation that uses multiple keys to map the value.